# Can tkinter progressbar go right-to-left?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The progressbar evolves from left to right, I would like to use it from right to left. Is it possible?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("Progressbar")
window.geometry('350x200')

bar = Progressbar(window, length=200)
bar.grid(column=0, row=0)
bar['value'] = 70

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

my question was stupid.
Cordially.
Marc.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("Progressbar")
window.geometry('350x200')

bar = Progressbar(window, length=200,maximum=70,              mode='indeterminate')
bar.grid(column=0, row=0)

#bar['value'] = 0 # Initialization on the left (value)
bar['value'] = 70 # Initialization on the right (value + maximum)
```

window.mainloop()